# Style of generated properties Vs C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I change the style of the properties that are generated by Visual studio?

This is what I get :

```
 public int Population {
            get {
                return _Population;
            }

            set {
                _Population = value;
            }
        }
```

This is what  i want :

```
public string Population
{
    get{return _Population;}
    set{_Population=value;}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for existing `propfull` code snippet.

So type propfull and press `Tab` twice your desired format will be created.

```
private int _Population;

public int Population
{
    get { return _Population; }
    set { _Population = value; }
}
```

**Edited:**Control the way code is formatted after `Refactor->Encapsulate Field`

Please note that Language Service formats code once its added using code-snippets. Hence, one can change the formatting of the code inserted after `Refactor->Encapsulate Field` by changing option `Leave block on single line` as `unchecked`. Its shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: i want it to be generated ,  when  i right click my prop and click on refactoring - encapsulte

Comment: @OrwaRa Can you add this into your question? It wasn´t clear to me - and oviously also to MKR - what you ment by "generate".

Comment: check i the picture i added

Comment: @OrwaRa I have edited to consider `Refactor` option.